# Removing many2many entity in typeorm with cascade

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity called `Entry` and it relates to another entity called `Image` as Many2Many.

Here is what the `Entry` & `Image` relationships look like:

```
@Entity('entry')
export class EntryEntity extends BaseEntity implements IDeserializable<EntryEntity> {
    @ManyToMany(type => ImageEntity, image => image.entries, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', cascade: true })
    @JoinTable()
    images: ImageEntity[];
}
```

and the `Image` entity class:

```
@Entity('image')
export class ImageEntity extends BaseEntity implements IDeserializable<ImageEntity> {
    @ManyToMany(type => EntryEntity, entry => entry.images)
    entries: EntryEntity[];
}
```

The method I use to delete an entry:

```
    public async delete(entryId: number): Promise<void> {
      const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
      await queryRunner.connect();
      await queryRunner.startTransaction();
      try {
        await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(EntryEntity)
                                 .createQueryBuilder('entry')
                                 .delete()
                                 .from(EntryEntity)
                                 .where('entry.id = :entryId', { entryId })
                                 .execute();
        await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
      } catch (err) {
        await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      } finally {
        await queryRunner.release();
      }
    }
```

*Expected behaviour:*

If I delete some entry then all its images should also be deleted.

*Factual behaviour:*

Entry gets removed from its table, it also gets removed from the `entry_images_image` table
but the images associated with this entry stay (they are still present in the `image` table).

I'm not very familiar with TypeOrm, why does it happen? I would highly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

what the cascade does is to remove the relations in both sides, not the entities themselves. so in you'r case, you will only receive images without relations, as you have mentioned.

Look at it like this: let's say that you have multiple images for multiple entries, all connected to each other. if you delete one entry, would you really like the image entity to be fully deleted? because in that case you will remove alot of data that hasn't been removed.